# Replace formulas with values and save it as a new file and change original file back to formulas afterwards

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel-File in which the user can click on a button to save a version **without formulas** and **only with values**. 
So far I use this VBA for it:

```
Sub Create_version_with_values_only()

Dim b As Worksheet
For Each b In Worksheets
b.Cells.Copy
b.Cells.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Next b

Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "G:\Folder\test.xlsm"
ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```

---

This VBA itself worsk fine.

However, the issue is that I have to close the file after the value-version of the file is created because the original version will not be available anymore.

Therefore, I am wondering if there is an alternative way to create the value-version of the file that makes it possible to go back to the original file afterwards.

Something like this:

**Step 1)** Change all formulas to values. 
**Step 2)** Save the version with the values in the folder.  
**Step 3)** Undo the value-replacements in original sheet without closing it.

Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Create a copy of the workbook first and change all formulas to values in the copy.

Comment: Side note: `b.Cells.Value = b.Cells.Value` converts to values w/o using the clipboard.

Comment: What VBA do I need to swtich to the copied file and make the formula-to-value conversion in there?

Comment: Why are you doing this? `SaveCopyAs` doesn't allow you to control the file type. You are using a `.xlsm` file which would suggest that you have some code in it. Do you really need this code in the copy? If you don't need it, you could do a simple `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Copy`, do the loop and value replacements on the `ActiveWorkbook` (which at this moment is the copy) and finish with e.g. `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "G:\Folder\test.xlsx", xlOpenXMLWorkbook` and `ActiveWorkbook.Close False`. It would be as nothing happened i.e. you're back in your initial workbook (you didn't touch it at all).

Comment: @VBasic2008 there shouldn't be any reason to suggest `ActiveWorkbook` to anyone on here. `ThisWorkbook` is available by default and leaves no room for silent failure. A reference to other workbooks is similarly easy to capture explicitly from the `Workbooks` collection

Comment: Are you doing this to the workbook containing this code, or is the code in an add-in or the `Personal.xlsb` workbook? If the former, then using `ThisWorkbook` instead of `ActiveWorkbook` is a must, as CallumDA is indicating in his comment. Please, do clarify.

Comment: @VBasic2008 OP states "I have an Excel-File in which [...]". I think that's clear enough that the code is in a normal workbook. We can discuss this elsewhere, but in add-ins I would always pass `ThisWorkbook` to the add-in so that there was no confusion about which workbook was in scope. Similarly, it's easy enough to call a proc saved in personal.xlsb from the immediate window and again pass `ThisWorkbook`. It's worth it so that you're not at the whim of `ActiveWorkbook` / `ActiveSheet`, potentially with unwanted consequences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a more simple way to get there, but here's how you'd create a new workbook, transfer the values over and save.

```
Public Sub SaveValues()
    Dim newWb As Workbook
    Set newWb = Workbooks.Add 'create a new workbook for the values
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, newWs As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    
        With newWb 'create worksheets and name them in new workbook
            If ws.Index = 1 Then
                Set newWs = .Worksheets(1)
            Else
                Set newWs = .Worksheets.Add(After:=.Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count))
            End If
            newWs.Name = ws.Name
        End With
    
        With ws.UsedRange 'move values to new worksheet
            newWs.Range("A1").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
        End With
    Next
    
    'save new workbook. If the current workbook is a .xlsb, change the .xlsm in the code below
    newWb.SaveAs Replace(ThisWorkbook.FullName, ".xlsm", "_hardcoded.xlsm"), xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
    newWb.Close
End Sub
```

Updated for alternatives below:

---

**Alternative**

An alternative is to use `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Copy` to copying all worksheets in one go. Unfortunately, to use this code, we have to use `ActiveWorkbook` to make a reference to the new workbook. (I hoped it might return a `Workbook` or `Worksheets` object)

```
Public Sub SaveValues2()
   Dim newWB As Workbook
   
   ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Copy
   Set newWB = ActiveWorkbook 'not great practice
   
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   For Each ws In newWB.Worksheets
        With ws.UsedRange 'hardcode values
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    Next

    newWB.SaveAs Replace(ThisWorkbook.FullName, ".xlsm", "_hardcoded.xlsm"), xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
    newWB.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Note that you are not transferring formats, the code, possible charts... all of which `SaveCopyAs` does.

Comment: @VBasic2008. OP asked for a version "only with values". I also explained precisely what my code does. At no point has OP stated they have charts, code, or formats that they want to keep. However, if that is the case, I welcome them (not you) to comment on my answer and let me know. I will happily accommodate clarifications of the original question. If there is something seriously wrong with my answer, please downvote it and then add a comment for explanation. Otherwise, please stop posting comments on helpful answers, nit-picking code for scenarios that haven't been confirmed in the question!

Comment: @BigBen thanks! I added the alternative for completeness (also added my reservations - might be a bit purist, but I'm sure we've both seen more than our fair share of questions relating to `Active[]` on here)

Comment: @CallumDA: Thanks a lot for both solutions (with and without formats). They work really well in one of my simple Excel-Sheets. However, I have more complex sheet and in this one I get runtime error 1004 on line newWs.Range("A1").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value in the first VBA and on line .Value = .Value in the second VBA. Do you have any idea why this could be the case?

Comment: @Michi no problem. Hard to say without seeing. Do you have any merged cells? What’s funky about that sheet that isn’t present on the other sheets?